# How to run Django and hardware code together on raspberry pi

Tags: django, apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm new to raspberry pi and Django. I'm creating an application that has a webpage (on Django) and some relays.
Django is working fine. It serving the page as http server and I have another small code in another py file.
I dont know how to make these things work together.
Django has manage.py file. Should I write my relay code into manage.py or should I have to create another py file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Interesting question. Is the code for your relays something that you call once (like you call a webpage) to e.g. toggle the relays or does it need to run permanently in the background in a loop?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the code will be run permanently in background in loop which will serve some data to django app.. user will open the web page and can see the data and change relay states